# find specific word in a string function is acting... odd (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I have this function that is suppose to log a specific word it finds in a string into the console. But it kinda... yeah it don't work.

```js
function foo(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const character = input[i]
    // To make sure it doesnt always get 
    // the very first blank space I do the following \/ (I think this is the trouble area)
    const word = input.substring(i, input.substring(i, input.length).indexOf(' '))
    console.log(word)
    if (word == "foo bar") {
      console.log(word)
      console.log("worked!") // <- currently does not fire
      // word should only print "foo bar" without linebreaks
    }
  }
}
foo("  foo bar  ");
```

I don't even know how to explain what is happening. But I am sure this scary image will give you an idea.

[image: web browser console]

the expected output, with some line breaks above or below, is: 
"f"
"fo"
"foo"
"foo "
"foo b"
"foo ba"
"foo bar"
"worked!"

ALSO keep it mind that this does not work with or without line breaks (I testing both) and I would like it to work with both.

examples:

```js
// single line (does not work)
foo("  foo bar   ")

// line breaks (does not work)
foo(`
    foo bar
`)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your question and edit the snippet I created with your HTML so we can test this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?retiredLocale=nl

Comment: What's your input? Also your described expected output is the output posted here. I assume it's not what you want, but fyi

Comment: Browsers have debuggers you can use for this sort of thing. Press f12 on your browser and look for a tab called "debugger" or "sources"

Comment: What is the `character` variable for?

Comment: @janilson the image I sent IS the debugger I am using

Comment: @disinfor unfortunately I dont know how to make it work so that you can test it in the console

Comment: @Barmar the character variable is going to be used for something else. I just forgot to remove it for the post. I will remove it now since it is unneeded.

Comment: @TCooper Sorry about that! Ima add that in now. I thought I already did that, but I guess not.

Comment: While you're editing, add a call to the function to the snippet.

Comment: I don't see any way that you could be getting one log message without the other. They're both in the same `if` block.

Comment: The code in the question cannot produce the output in the image. You probably have an additional `console.log(word)` just before the line `if (word == "foo bar")`. That `console.log()` produces the output (it produces a different output for me). The condition `word == "foo bar"` is never met and the two `console.log()` inside the `if` block are not executed.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but the thing is the if block never gets true so it never fires

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `if (input.match(/\bfoo bar\b/)) { console.log("worked!"); }`?

Comment: The second argument to `substring()` is an index, but you're calculating a length by getting the index in the substring that starts from `i`.

Comment: @barmar I did not know this existed, let me try that!

Comment: If the if block never fires, why does your sample output show all those log messages? When I run the code in your snippet there's no output at all.

Comment: `indexOf()` has an optional starting index. You want `input.indexOf(" ", i);`

Comment: I am sorry yall, I thought I planned out this post well but apparently I didnt and I missed a lot. My fault.

Comment: @Barmar I did const word = input.indexOf(" ", i) instead of what I already had. Didnt work, just spat out a buncha numbers: 1 8(3 times) -1(4 times)

Comment: Notice that lots of your log messages have spaces at the beginning. You need to skip over those to find the beginning of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `word` out of the for loop... And add the current character to it at each iteration.

```js
const input = "foo bar"

function foo(input) {
  let word = ""  // Define it out of the loop
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const character = input[i]
    word += character  // add the current loop character here
    
    console.log(word)
    
    if (word == "foo bar") {
      console.log("worked!") // <- is firing now
    }
  }
}

foo(input)
```

From comment:

> if I have the string "This is a foo bar lalalalala" I want to get just the "foo bar" part.

Then using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) would be the way.

```js
const input = "This is a foo bar lalalalala"

function foo(input) {
  let match = input.match(/foo bar/)

  if (match) {
    console.log("worked!") // <- is firing now
  }
}

foo(input)
```

Comment: This would work, but in my case I want to find words or just certain parts in a string for example if I have the string "This is a foo bar lalalalala" I want to get just the "foo bar" part.

Comment: Thank you! your edit solved my issue. Really appreciate your help :D